# Setting an alphabetic citation style in LyX

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, lyx, citing

How can I get LyX to use a different citation style? Instead of the numeric citations `[1]` I would like abbreviations of the author names and a 2-figure year: `[EPR35]`. I believe the `alphaabbrv` style does this, but any roughly equivalent style would be fine.

`[1] A. Einstein, B. Podolsky, and N. Rosen, Can quantum-mechanical description of physical reality be considered complete? Phys. Rev. 47 777 (1935)`

Answer (score 7):

I don't know why this was never answered. But for reference, in case anyone else sees this.

When you do Insert --> List/ToC --> BibTeX bibliography, you get this window:

[image]

The `\bibliographystyle` is chosen by the *Style* drop-down menu. Choose the one you want from the list. There is no style called `alphaabbrv` in the list, but `alpha` does something like what you're after (see screenshot at the bottom).

To open this dialog after having added a bibliography in the first place, right click *BibTeX Generated Bibliography*, and click on *settings*.

[image]

## Screenshot of example with `alpha`

[image]

Comment: Worked for me. Also for the reference, the (useless) option in document->settings->bibliography is overriden by this setting.